# Get Data From one SQL Server to Other SQL server (using C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I want the code for copy data from one sql to another sql (Using C#)

When I click the Button

Copy my `db2_connect` Database data like:

```
select * from importdb where bhand = 3 and store = 14
```

To my another database which is:
**abdConnection**

in abdConnection Table is importabd and filed is same (`bhand`)

Can someone write the complete code.

Thanking You

Comment: _Can someone write the complete code_ **NO!** This is not a good way to ask here. Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select bhand from importdb where bhand = 3 and store = 14", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionStringTo2ndDB");
    connection2.Open();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into importabd ('bhand') values ('" +  reader[0]+"')", connection2);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    connection2.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you please see my code and tell me how i fix this error.
Thanks.

Comment: You have not set the connection for the command to use. SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MM410LIB.INVBAL WHERE INUMBR = 79610 AND ISTORE=14", this.cn); Also you are using ODBC so try using OdbcDataReader DbReader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Yes I'm using ODBC Connection, and thru this I am connecting with AS400 DB2.

Comment: Now what i need to change, 
Should I use this:

            OdbcConnection odbcco = new OdbcConnection("SELECT * FROM MM410LIB.INVBAL WHERE INUMBR = 79610 AND ISTORE=14");
            //OdbcConnection command = new OdbcConnection("SELECT * FROM MM410LIB.INVBAL WHERE INUMBR = 79610 AND ISTORE=14");

Comment: I post new answer and showing all code, can you please check and suggest.

Comment: If you do just send a link and I can look at it. And remember that you must add your created connection to the command OdbcConnection command = new OdbcConnection(CommandString, OdbcConnection);

Comment: You must also remember to open the OdbcConnection like so OdbcConnection.Open(); before the execution of the command

Answer (score 0):

try this sql command in button click event

```
insert into [server2name].adbconnection.dbo.tablename(select * from[server1name].  
    importdb.abo.tablename where bhand=3 and store-14)
```

Comment: Before this i need to add this connection thru there user and password?

Comment: yeah you have to add sql connection string before the sql command  also in sqlserver goto serverobject -> linked servers ,rightclick ->newlinked Server then add your target server as linked server